# what's the best authentication method for BlackBerry

Tags: java, php, blackberry

I'm developing a Java app for blackberry, in this app I have a login form
I'm using basic authentication for the moment to pass the user and password to a page that calls a PHP script that receives the parameters.

I don't like this method cause it stores the parameters and they cant be erased until you kill the browser or the app. I want to be able to logout without leaving the app.

Is there a better or safer or practical way? To authenticate trough Blackberry!

Comment: Which 'it' stores the parameters? The blackberry? or PHP? Can't you just add a logout button which deletes the user credentials/cookie?

Comment: if i delete the cookies it will work in php (tried before) but the blackberry doesnt process it... y problem is with the blackberry java app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should using StreamConnection to make a HTTP or HTTPS Connection to the PHP script.
Make sure you are using POST method
this will be using setRequestMethod("POST")

The PHP script should just receive the parameters, and check it to your database.
If success then return "success", or "fail" if the authentication process is fail

You should find using these classes

StremConnection, HttpConnection,Connector,InputStream,OutputStream